# phpmyadmin not working in webmin

Tags: php

I had installed phpmyadmin in my Redhat Linux server machine (64bit).  After installation when I tried to access the same with the URL `domain.com/phpmyadmin`, it is showing an error:

```
The requested URL /phpmyadmin/navigation.php< was not found on this server.
```

then I tried to access `domain.com/phpmyadmin/setup`, it is showing this error:

```
<?
/* @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GNU GPL 2.0 */
/**
 * Core libraries.
 */
require './lib/common.inc.php';
$page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page');
$page = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $page);
if ($page === '') { $page = 'index'; }
if (!file_exists("./setup/frames/$page.inc.php")) {
  // it will happen only when enterung URL by hand, we don't care for these cases
  die(__('Wrong GET file attribute value'));
}

// Handle done action info
$action_done = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action_done');
$action_done = preg_replace('/[^a-z_]/', '', $action_done);
// send no-cache headers
require './libraries/header_http.inc.php';
?>
```

and below this error only displaying "phpMyAdmin setup" and that's all. Also I had a try to access `phpinfo.php` in phpmyadmin folder and its showing a blank page.

Websites pages with PHP are working fine.

Comment: Hello,welcome, please try improving your question so we can try to help you : Is it rhel 6? How did you try to install phpmyadmin eg yum install phpmyadmin or followed tutorial at http://foobar.example.com ?

Comment: thanks for the quick responce. yes its rhel 6, and i tried tarball and when it throwed the same error i just tried yum install also. i followed [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-redhat-linux-installing-phpmyadmin-webtool/) link

Comment: Can you provide apache configuration and logs please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, httpd.conf was causing issues. when i removed virtual servers created through webmin, got it worked. and reconfigured the same.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@ebugs.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/ebugs"
    ServerName ebuqs.com
    ServerAlias www.ebugs.com
    ErrorLog "logs/ebugs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/ebugs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@startfromthegrub.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/docs/startfromthegrub"
    ServerName startfromthegrub.com
    ServerAlias www.startfromthegrub.com
    ErrorLog "logs/startfromthegrub/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/startfromthegrub/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```